# Support Push Notification in iOS 8,9, 10 and 11

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have setup the push notification in the AppDelegate as follows. I wonder is there a better way to handle?

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) 
{
  #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                         | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  #endif
} 
else 
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0") ||SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(@"11.0") )
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *notifiCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    notifiCenter.delegate = self;
    [notifiCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
        if( !error ){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }];
}
```